# Python / Django NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

I'm giving Python / Django a ago, going alright so far. I'm in the middle of setting up Django authentication, but I've hit a error;

```
Reverse for 'user_review_list' not found. 'user_review_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Here are my views:

```
def user_review_list(request, username=None):
if not username:
    username = request.user.username
latest_review_list = Review.objects.filter(user_name=username).order_by('-pub_date')
context = {'latest_review_list':latest_review_list, 'username':username}
return render(request, 'reviews/user_review_list.html', context)
```

In my base.html I call the following:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'reviews:user_review_list' user.username %}">Hello {{ user.username }}</li>
```

I've checked my other html templates and they all seem to be calling it correctly, is there anything I'm missing?

EDIT: URL's

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^reviews/', include(('reviews.urls', 'reviews'), namespace='reviews')),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ]
```

Apps URL's

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'reviews'

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /
    url(r'^$', views.review_list, name='review_list'),
    # ex: /product/5/
    url(r'^review/(?P<review_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
    # ex: /product/
    url(r'^product$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    # ex: /product/5/
    url(r'^product/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    url(r'^product/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$', views.add_review, name='add_review'),
]
```

Comment: post the urls file too

Comment: Updated my question with URL's

Comment: the apps url too

Comment: Okay updated the question

Comment: you dont have a name `user_review_list` in your app url, then how can you use it

Comment: wow, okay I was using a old URL's file for some reason, should have noticed that `user_review_list` was missing. Thank you all working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Exprator pointed out I was missing `user_review_list` from my app URL's.

Answer (score 0):

Review.objects.filter() will return a list. 
For a single user, you should use Review.objects.get() method

Comment: Ah yes thats a great way of shortening that line, didn't realise .get would do the same thing. - Thank you,

Comment: @cal, if it solves your problem, please accept this answer.